# Is there a way to tell stack that I want to use an older resolver by default?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How would I configure stack to use an older resolver by default?

I know the resolver can be specified on the command line at build time and per project in the project configuration or at project creation time.   Is there a way to set it so that every new project that I create defaults to a specific older resolver?

I tried configuring stack with `stack setup --resolver=lts-15.2` but `stack new <projectname>` still defaults to the latest lts resolver.

Comment: If specifying the resolver with every `stack new` invocation seems to inconvenient, I'd suggest you make a feature request. I'm not aware of a different way of configuring the resolver used for `stack new`.

Comment: If you know that there is no way to do what I want to do, please state it as an answer (ideally with some additional explanation) and I'll accept it.

Comment: It looks like it should be set in `~/.stack/config.yaml`, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: radrow, that was my thought as well.   I couldn't get it to work either but I might have been using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I set stack's resolver at the global level by modifying  `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`. In my case I included the line:

```
resolver: lts-18.28
```